# Why it is not reading contacts from the file correctly

Tags: c++

I am making C++ project "phonebook". Here I am testing two functionalities(Adding contacts and displaying the saved contacts).When I am adding more than 4 contacts and trying to read from the file. It is not reading correctly. Please do let know where I am doing wrong.

I am sorry for pasting here big code but this is the minimal code that will be required for analysis.
Below is my code:

```
//****************************************************PHONEBOOK.H***********************************************************//
#define ADD_CONTACT 1
class phonebook
{
//details of contact:

//mandatory details to store a contact
char first_name[30];
char last_name[30];

//one is mandatory
char mobile_num[30];
char work_num[30];
char home_num[30];

//additional details for a contact
char company_name[30];
char job_title[30];
char email[30];
char location[30];
char dob[30];

bool favorite_flag;
bool friend_flag;
bool family_flag;
bool office_flag;

bool name_order;
//flags of details whether present or not:
bool company_name_present;
bool job_title_present;
bool email_present;
bool location_present;
bool dob_present;
bool relation_present;
bool mobile_num_flag;
bool work_num_flag;
bool home_num_flag;

//link for linked list(dll)
phonebook* link,*prev;
bool check_number_valid(char*);
void reverse_linked_list(phonebook* &);
void print_all_the_details(phonebook* &);
friend void operator>>(istream&,phonebook*&);
friend void operator<<(ostream&,phonebook*&);

public:
  phonebook();
~phonebook()
{}
phonebook* add_contact(phonebook*);

void display()
{
   phonebook *temp;
   if(this==NULL)
     cout<<"null"<<endl;
   else
  {
     for(temp=this;temp;temp=temp->link)
     cout<<temp;
  }
}
phonebook* file_sync_phonebook();
bool save_phonebook_file();


};
phonebook::phonebook()
{

favorite_flag=0;
friend_flag=0;
family_flag=0;
office_flag=0;
mobile_num_flag=0;
work_num_flag=0;
home_num_flag=0;

company_name_present=0;
job_title_present=0;
email_present=0;
location_present=0;
dob_present=0;
relation_present=0;

name_order=0;

link=NULL;
prev=NULL;
}

phonebook* phonebook::file_sync_phonebook()
{

ifstream file_in;

file_in.open("phonebook.txt");
phonebook *read_obj,*traverse_pointer=NULL,*head_ref=NULL;

if(file_in)
{

  file_in.seekg(0,ios::end);
  long long int size=file_in.tellg();
  file_in.seekg(0);

if(size==0)
{
   head_ref=NULL;
   file_in.close();
}
else
{

   while(file_in)
  {
    read_obj=new phonebook;
    file_in.read((char*)read_obj,sizeof(read_obj));

    if(head_ref==NULL)
   {
      head_ref=read_obj;
      read_obj=NULL;
   }
  else
  {
   for(traverse_pointer=head_ref;traverse_pointer->link;traverse_pointer=traverse_pointer->link);
       traverse_pointer->link=read_obj;
        read_obj->prev=traverse_pointer;

  read_obj=NULL;
 }
}
 file_in.close();
}
}
else
  head_ref=NULL;

return head_ref;
}

bool phonebook::save_phonebook_file()
{
  if(this)
  {
     phonebook *traverse_pointer=NULL;
     fstream file_out;
     file_out.open("phonebook.txt",ios::out | ios::trunc);
    for(traverse_pointer=this;traverse_pointer;traverse_pointer=traverse_pointer->link)
   {
      file_out.write((char*)traverse_pointer,sizeof(*traverse_pointer));
   }

file_out.close();
return 1;
}
else
 return 0;
}

void print_phonebook_menu()
{
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_MAXIMIZE);
    system("cls");
    system("Color 3F");
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  *WELCOME TO PHONEBOOK APPLICATION*";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ======================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t|PHONE BOOK APPLICATION|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ======================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                        "<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMAIN MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t======================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[1] Add a new Contact\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[2] Delete Contact\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[3] Update a Contact\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[4] Show a Contact\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[5] Display Contacts\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[6] Settings\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[7] Exit\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ======================="<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEnter your choice:";
}
void operator<<(ostream& out,phonebook* &obj)
{
   if(obj->name_order)
  {
     out<<obj->last_name;
     out<<" "<<obj->first_name;
  }
  else
 {
   out<<obj->first_name;
   out<<" "<<obj->last_name;
 }

if(obj->mobile_num_flag)
 cout<<" Mobile: "<<obj->mobile_num;

if(obj->work_num_flag)
 cout<<" Work: "<<obj->work_num;

if(obj->home_num_flag)
 cout<<" Home: "<<obj->home_num<<endl;;

cout<<endl;
}
void operator>>(istream& in,phonebook* &obj)
{
int num_in;

char ch;

cout<<"Enter First Name:"<<endl;
in>>obj->first_name;
fflush(stdin);

cout<<"Enter Last Name:"<<endl;
in>>obj->last_name;
fflush(stdin);

ENTER_NUMBER_CHOICE_AGAIN:

cout<<"Type of number.\n 1.Mobile Number\n2.Work Number\n3.Home Number"<<endl;

in>>num_in;
fflush(stdin);

switch(num_in)
{
  case 1: ENTER_MOBILE_NUMBER_AGAIN:
  cout<<"Enter Mobile Number."<<endl;
  in>>obj->mobile_num;
  obj->mobile_num_flag=1;
  fflush(stdin);
  if(obj->check_number_valid(obj->mobile_num))
    break;
  else
  {
    cout<<"number invalid"<<endl;
    cout<<"enter again"<<endl;
    goto ENTER_MOBILE_NUMBER_AGAIN;
  }

 case 2: ENTER_WORK_NUMBER_AGAIN:
cout<<"Enter Work Number."<<endl;
in>>obj->work_num;
obj->work_num_flag=1;
fflush(stdin);

if(obj->check_number_valid(obj->work_num))
  break;
else
{
  cout<<"number invalid"<<endl;
  cout<<"enter again"<<endl;
  goto ENTER_WORK_NUMBER_AGAIN;
}
case 3: ENTER_HOME_NUMBER_AGAIN:
      cout<<"Enter Home Number."<<endl;
      in>>obj->home_num;
      obj->home_num_flag=1;
      fflush(stdin);

if(obj->check_number_valid(obj->home_num))
   break;
else
{
  cout<<"number invalid"<<endl;
  cout<<"enter again"<<endl;
  goto ENTER_HOME_NUMBER_AGAIN;
}

default:
cout<<"wrong choice"<<endl;
goto ENTER_NUMBER_CHOICE_AGAIN;
}
cout<<"Add some more details? press Y else any key"<<endl;
in>>ch;
fflush(stdin);
if(ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
{
   bool BREAK_WHILE=0;
   int relation_flag;
   int i;
  while(1)
 {

   if(BREAK_WHILE)
   break;

  ENTER_CHOICE_AGAIN:
  cout<<"1.COMPANY NAME\n2.JOB TITLE\n3.Email\n4.Location\n5.DOB\n6.Relation\n7.Leave"<<endl;
  in>>i;
  fflush(stdin);

switch(i)
{
  case 1: if(!(obj->company_name_present))
{
  cout<<"Enter Company Name:"<<endl;
  in>>obj->company_name;
  obj->company_name_present=1;
  fflush(stdin);
  break;
}
else
{
  cout<<"company name exist. To update use update contact feature."<<endl;
  break;
}
case 2: if(!(obj->job_title_present))
{
  cout<<"Enter Job Title:"<<endl;
  in>>obj->job_title;
  obj->job_title_present=1;
  fflush(stdin);
  break;
}
else
{
  cout<<"Job Title exist. To update use update contact feature."<<endl;
  break;
}
case 3: if(!(obj->email_present))
{
   ENTER_EMAIL_AGAIN:
   cout<<"Enter Email:"<<endl;
   in>>obj->email;
   obj->email_present=1;
   fflush(stdin);
   break;
}
else
{
   cout<<"Email exist. To update use update contact feature."<<endl;
   break;
}
case 4: if(!(obj->location_present))
{
   cout<<"Enter Location(only place):"<<endl;
   in>>obj->location;
   obj->location_present=1;
   fflush(stdin);
  break;
}
else
{
   cout<<"Location exist. To update use update contact feature."<<endl;
   break;
}
case 5: if(!(obj->dob_present))
{
cout<<"Enter DOB(dd/mm/yyyy):"<<endl;
in>>obj->dob;
obj->dob_present=1;
fflush(stdin);
break;
}
else
{
   cout<<"DOB exist. To update use update contact feature."<<endl;
   break;
}

case 6: cout<<"1.Friend\n2.Family\n3.Office"<<endl;
in>>relation_flag;
if(relation_flag==1)
obj->friend_flag=1;
else if(relation_flag==2)
obj->family_flag=1;
else if(relation_flag=3)
obj->office_flag=1;
else
cout<<"wrong choice"<<endl;

break;

case 7: BREAK_WHILE=1;break;

default: cout<<"wrong choice"<<endl;
goto ENTER_CHOICE_AGAIN;

}
}

cout<<"Want to add this contact to favourites? Press Y or N."<<endl;
in>>ch;
if(ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
obj->favorite_flag=1;


}

}
phonebook* phonebook::add_contact(phonebook* head)
{
    phonebook *temp=NULL,*traverse_pointer=NULL,*head_ref=head;

    temp=new phonebook;

    cin>>temp;

    if(head_ref==NULL)
    head_ref=temp;
    else
    {
        for(traverse_pointer=head_ref;traverse_pointer->link;traverse_pointer=traverse_pointer->link);
        traverse_pointer->link=temp;
        temp->prev=traverse_pointer;
    }

    if(head_ref->save_phonebook_file())
    cout<<"Contact Saved Successfully"<<endl;
    else
    cout<<"Save Unsuccessful."<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return head_ref;
}

bool phonebook::check_number_valid(char *p)
{
   if(strlen(p)>10 || (strlen(p))<10)
      return false;

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     if(p[i]<'0' || p[i]>'9')
      return false;

 return true;
}

void print_phonebook_menu();
/**************************************MAIN.CPP****************************************/
int main()
{
  phonebook *head,*temp;
  head=head->file_sync_phonebook();
  int input_for_phonebook_menu,settings_choice;
  bool BREAK_WHILE=0;

  while(1)
 {
   print_phonebook_menu();
   cin>>input_for_phonebook_menu;
   fflush(stdin);

   switch(input_for_phonebook_menu)
  {
      case ADD_CONTACT : if(admin_flag==1)
  {
      head=head->add_contact(head); break;
  }
else
{
   cout<<"user cannot access.Login as Admin."<<endl; system("pause"); break;
}

case 2                  :     head->display();
                          system("pause");break;
default : cout<<"Wrong Choice, Enter Choice Again."<<endl; 
           system("pause"); break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is definitively not a minimal example or are you saying that the error doesn't persist if you e.g. remove `email` from everywhere? It is also not complete or reproducible, since you have not provided the input you are using, the output you are getting and the output you expected.

Comment: You should be opening the file in binary mode, especially on Windows where not doing that can easily break things in difficult to figure out ways.

Comment: Yet another O.T. hint: Your prof. will like your code more with a proper indentation. Your exposed code is (sorry) terribly formatted. It's very hard to recognize the structure of your code. FYI: [Indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) (My personal favorite is K&R with mandatory curly braces.) ;-)

Comment: You should also consider using array instead of a billion of bool or char [30], it would be much more readable